# Extracting elemental ratios from X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS)

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Is it possible to extract information on elemental ratios from X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS)?  For example, I am reading a paper and in it they say that the carbon to oxygen (C:O) ratios of the four samples are 2.8, 2.9, 5.1, and 23.3.  However, the authors do not provide the actual XPS spectra, not even in a Supporting Information-type addendum.

I am a computational chemist and have no experience with XPS.  I do know that elements, and even particular hybridizations, give characteristic peaks at characteristic binding energies (in units of eV, for example).  This, I know, enables *qualitative* analysis of compounds.  But is there a way to extract *quantitative* information from XPS?  Suppose I want to determine the C:O ratio in a compound containing only C, O, and H.  Do I take the ratio of the C and O peak heights, or do I take the ratio of the area under the peaks corresponding to C and O?

Do you know of any good review articles that would help me to understand the basics of XPS?

Comment: ""and even particular hybridizations, give characteristic peaks at characteristic binding energies (in units of eV, for example)"" You mix up photoelectron spectroscopy and X-Ray-PES

Comment: @Georg Thanks. What is the difference between photoelectron spectroscopy and X-ray-PES?

Comment: The latter uses Röntgen-rays, the other vacuum-UV to set free those electrons. That means that only the highest level electrons are expelled (carrying information on chemical bonds) or electrons "deep" in the atoms are expelled by Röntgen-rays, giving information on elemetary composition.

Comment: @Georg XPS can also give chemical information (through less sensitive than UPS).

Answer (score 3):

I found some information in Skoog, *Principles of Instrumental Analysis*, 6th ed.  On page 597:

> **Quantitative Applications.**  Once, XPS was not considered to be a very useful quantitative technique. However, there has been increasing
>   use of XPS for determining the chemical composition of the surface
>   region of solids.  If the solid is homogenous to a depth of several
>   electron mean free paths, we can express the number of photoelectrons
>   detected each second $I$ as $$I = n \phi \sigma \epsilon \eta A T \ell$$ where $n$ is the number density of atoms ($\text{atoms cm}^{-3}$) of the sample, $\phi$ is the flux of the incident X-ray
>   beam ($\text{photons cm}^{-2} \text{ s}^{-1}$), $\sigma$ is the
>   photoelectric cross section for the transition
>   ($\text{cm}^{2}/\text{atom}$), $\epsilon$ is the angular efficiency
>   factor for the instrument, $\eta$ is the efficiency of producing photo
>   electrons ($\text{photoelectrons/photon}$), $A$ is the area of the
>   sample from which photoelectrons are detected ($\text{cm}^{2}$), $T$
>   is the efficiency of detection of the photoelectrons, and $\ell$ is
>   the mean free path of the photoelectrons in the sample ($\text{cm}$).
>
> For a given transition, the last six terms are constant, and we can
>   write the atomic sensitivity factor $S$ as $$S = \sigma \epsilon \eta A T \ell$$  For a given spectrometer, a set of relative values of $S$
>   can be developed for the elements of interest.  Note that the $I/S$ is
>   directly porportional to the concentration $n$ on the surface.  The
>   quantity $I$ is usually taken as the peak area, although peak heights
>   are also used.  Often, for quantitative work, internal standards are
>   used.  Relative precisions of about 5% are typical.  For the analysis
>   of solids and liquids, it is necessary to assume that the surface
>   composition of the sample is the same as its bulk composition.  For
>   many applications this assumption can lead to significant errors. 
>   Detection of an element by XPS requires that it be present at a level
>   of at least 0.1%.  Quantitative analysis can usually be performed if
>   5% of the element is present.